# Unix FTP connection get file based on time stamp

Tags: unix, ftp

I have a requirement to connect to an FTP server from Unix, and download a particular file which has the most recent date/time stamp.

For example here is what the file name might look like: FILE_NAME_W5215.ZIP 
The "W5215" part is the date/time stamp.

If I was to try and get the latest file locally I would do something like this:

```
ls -t FILE_NAME_W*.ZIP | head -1
```

however that doesn't work on the remote server.

I don't know what OS the FTP server is running on. I know that when I establish the connection, a lot of the commands that I can do locally on Unix don't work when I'm connected to the FTP.

Any ideas, thoughts, suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is your question exactly? What problem are you facing? Also, I don't understand how W5215 could be timestamp?

Comment: I'm with you, but this is how the geniuses here are naming the file. Maybe it's not so much a time stamp but a version, so I need to get the latest one, i.e. the greatest value. Normally I would do something like:                          ls -t FILE_NAME_*.ZIP | head -1

Comment: But that doesn't work when i'm connected to the FTP server

Comment: These are shell commands, they won't work inside ftp. If you cannot derive the filename beforehand, then, first you need to get the list of files. Outside ftp, sort the list and extract the latest filename, then again do a ftp get using the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Get the file list on ftp server in a temp file

```
ftp -n $SERVER >tempfile <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
ls -t
quit
EOF
```

Get the latest filename from the list

```
filename=`cut -c57- tempfile|head -1`
```

Note: In ls file list, filename starts from the 57th position, change it if necessary

Now get that particular filename from ftp server

```
ftp -n $SERVER<<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
get $filename
quit
EOF
```